# C# UserControl depends of form it is place in - WinForms

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have problem like below,

I need to create `UserControl` that is placed in different forms.
But it's behaviour depends of the form it is placed in.

**Example:**
`Form1` has button that takes data from db and sends it to my `UserControl`.Then it creates let's say another control that can be clicked but when clicked it calls db (depends on `Form1`) and crates new controls below.

`Form2` does the same but different db calls.

Problem form me is how calls the second call from `UserControl` - how make query to db when it depends on from external form used?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an ABSOLUTELY HORRIBLE design, but this is how you'd do it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ParentForm != null)
    {
        if (this.ParentForm is Form1)
        {
            Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.ParentForm; // if you need a reference to the Form1 instance
            // ... do stuff for Form1 ...
        }
        else if (this.ParentForm is Form2)
        {
            Form2 f2 = (Form2)this.ParentForm; // if you need a reference to the Form2 instance
            // ... do stuff for Form2 ...
        }
        else if (...)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. But I wasn't clear. UserControl is used in different programs. It works in similar way but it must call different query in each form/program.